# create dynamic default values for column in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, callback, migration, one-to-many

I am not sure how to go about this, or if there is a better way to do this, but I have a table called leads(many) and it references agent (one).

I want to make a migration that sets a default value for the agent_id column in the leads table. But i want the default value to loop through all the agent ids. Im not sure how to do this!? Should i use a call back, or should i do in migration file?

Here is the actual question im trying to tackle:

When new leads are created assign it to an agent using a “round robin” That way new leads are distributed evenly across all the agents.

Ive attached a screenshot using SUDO code (i know its not functional as is) as to what I am thinking of doing. Any tips?

(Using ruby on rails w/ postgresql)

[image]

Comment: so each `lead` should have the unique `agent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it makes sense to handle this functionality as part of the main app, and not within migration, as there seem to be a significant chunk of functionality to handle.

Probably best to handle it as part of an `after_create` callback in the `Lead` model, and use a class variable  to track the next agent to be assigned as follows:

```
class Lead
  # Assign the class variable to the first agent
  @@next_agent = Agent.first
  after_create :set_agent

  ...

  private

  # Called by the after_create callback
  # Sets the agent_id, and updates the @@next_agent class variable
  def set_agent
    self.agent_id = @@next_agent.id
    @@next_agent = find_next_agent
  end

  ## Called from the set_agent method
  ## Finds the next agent based on the current value of @@next_agent
  def find_next_agent
    @@next_agent = Agent.find(@@next_agent.id + 1)
    @@next_agent = Agent.first unless @next_agent
  end
end
```

The `find_next_agent` logic above is a simplistic example, assuming that all Agent objects have ids that increment by 1, and there are no gaps (i.e. no deletions in the table).

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for!

I have some follow up questions about your proposed solution:
-Why do you use a class variable instead of an instance variable for @@next_agent?
-Why do you use after_create:set_agent not use before_create :set_agent, as before_create works too?

Comment: It has to be a class variable and not an instance variable as it has to be unique across instances. An instance variable has a value that is different for each instance. A class variable will have the same value no matter which instance it is accessed from.